# Is it possible to sort all my songs collection (in iTunes) by bitrate?

Tags: mp3, libraries, bitrate

The reason I want to do this is that I would like to change the bitrate of all of my songs superior to 192 kbps, so I get more storage in my iPod classic. My library has been gathered for years now and it's already surpassed 1 tb, so it is a pain in the neck to check álbum by álbum. If I could directly see which ones are above 192 kbps by using some kind of script or similar that would be awesome.
Thank you all so much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can keep the current bitrate on your computer in iTunes, but have it convert on the fly when it syncs to your iDevice.

Best of both worlds.

[image]

Alternatively, in Songs view, right click the columns bar & add Bitrate. You can then sort on that column.

Comment: Oh thanks a lot! I though that option only converted audio files to 128 kbps, which is a far than good quality. That's why I wanted to go for 192 kbps, which is at least more listenable. Did not know you could set the framework.

Comment: 128 acc is plenty for an iPod.